# How to display the users with matching record field using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Display the users with matching ID fields

staff details should only return when staffID(employer table) == id(staff table)

Below is my database schema

```
Staff('id' , 'username' , 'location');

Employer('id' , 'employerID','staffID' );
```

Below is what I have tried , however it is not return anything , i also have it returning to my blade file and a `@foreach` loop to get the data.
I've tried have a model methods but no luck.

```
   $following =  DB::table('staff')
    ->select('username')
   ->join('employer' , 'employer.staffID', '=', 'staff.id')
    ->where('employer.employer_id' , '=', Auth::id())
    ->where('employer.staffID' ,'=', 'staff.id') 
    ->get();
```

below is how I am trying to get my querys results to display in my blade

```
 @foreach ($following as $userFound)

                        <p> {{ $userFound->username}}</p>                 

 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

with raw SQL

```
$query = "SELECT username 
          FROM employer JOIN staff ON employee.staffID = staff.id
          WHERE employerID = ?";
$params = [Auth::id()];

$following = \DB::select($query , $params);
```

Comment: hi alli , a simple left join did the trick. thanks anyways